# SSL error using python(2.7) requests

Tags: python, ssl, python-requests

I am unable to issue a request to piratebay using `requests` with `python2.7`. I did the same with `python3.4` and it worked ok. The line which I'm trying to execute:

`r = requests.get("http://thepiratebay.se/browse/201", verify=False)`

I did the `verify=False` to try and escape all the SSL jargon to no avail. It's a small personal project anyway..

I also tried to change the version of SSL using this [link](https://lukasa.co.uk/2013/01/Choosing_SSL_Version_In_Requests/), however it still is giving me

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:510: error:14077438:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert internal error.`
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The site thepiratebay.se requires [Server Name Indication (SNI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) and will throw an alert if the client does not support it. While python3 supported SNI for a while already with python2.7 SNI was only added with version 2.7.9. My guess is that you are using an older version of python 2.7 and that's why run into this error.

Comment: My version is 2.7.6, so I guess you're right.. I ended changing to `python3` again and opening the magnet link in transmission directly. I was just complicating things trying to use libtorrent. Oh well! Thank you for your answer.